# Is there a find number of RCUs consumed by a query to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have one table in DynamoDB.
My service has 2 domain objects mapped to that table.

Table looks something like this,
id, name, title, attributemap

Domain objects are like this,
Content { id, name, title }
ContentAttribute { id, attributeMap }

I have a dao for each domain object.

My question is, when I do a get using the ContentAttribute dao, does dynamoDB fetch the entire row, or just the fields corresponding to the ContentAttribute domain object?

Is there a way to find out the number of RCUs consumed by one such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every read/write operation on DynamoDB allows you to request that it also returns the consumed capacity [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ReturnConsumedCapacity).

For example, on `GetItem` adding `ReturnConsumedCapacity: TOTAL` to the request will return a [ConsumedCapacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ConsumedCapacity.html) object detailing the capacity used by that query alone.

To answer your specific question, though, you always consume the complete item when you get from Dynamo, regardless of what attributes you ask to return [(more detail here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Reads):

> For any operation that returns items, you can request a subset of attributes to retrieve; however, doing so has no impact on the item size calculations.